# Pandas How to create a new dataframe with a start and end even if on different rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns.  Some of the `MessageID's` end on the same row that they start with the `NewMessageID` like in index row 0 below.  But others like index row 2 doesnt end until index row 4.  I am looking for a clever way to simplify the output in a new dataframe.

```
df
    MessageID   NewMessageID
0   28          10
1   21          9
2   4           18
3   3           6
4   18          22
5   99          102
6   102         118
7   1           20
```

I am looking for an output like:

```
df1
    Start  Finish
0   28     10 
1   21     9
2   4      22
3   3      6
4   99     118
5   1      20
```

Comment: So you want the "transitive closure" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using a library called `networkx`

```
G = (nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
      df, source='MessageID', target='NewMessageID', create_using=nx.DiGraph()))

tc = nx.algorithms.dag.transitive_closure(G)

a = df['MessageID'].to_numpy()
b = df['NewMessageID'].to_numpy()

d = pd.DataFrame(tc.edges)

d[~d[1].isin(a) & ~d[0].isin(b)]
```

```
    0    1
0  28   10
1  21    9
3   4   22
5   3    6
7  99  118
9   1   20
```

Comment: When I try this one I get AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
when I execute a = test['MessageID'].to_numpy() @user3483203

Comment: Then use `.values` instead of `.to_numpy()`

Comment: Nice solution. I had thought about `[*nx.topological_sort(G)]` but honestly had no idea how that could have failed. Always good to learn some more graph theory from solutions like this.

Answer (score 5):

Join on itself, to create `df2`, drop rows from original `df` which have common values between the two columns.  Keep the outer two columns of `df2` and rename them to match `df` and append one to the other.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'MessageID':[28,21,4,3,18,99,102,1],'NewMessageID':[10,9,18,6,22,102,118,20]})

df2 = df.merge(df, left_on='NewMessageID', right_on='MessageID')
df2 = df2[['MessageID_x','NewMessageID_y']]
df2.columns = ['MessageID', 'NewMessageID']

df = df[(~df['MessageID'].isin(df['NewMessageID'].values.tolist())) & (~df['NewMessageID'].isin(df['MessageID'].values.tolist()))]

output = df.append(df2)


              MessageID  NewMessageID
    0         28            10
    1         21             9
    3          3             6
    7          1            20
    0          4            22
    1         99           118
```

Answer (score 3):

I have yet another solution, since I noticed the most up-voted solution will not work in a scenario where there are more than two rows to be linked. I added yet another connection, from 22 -> 23 to show that it works in such a scenario.

```
def main():
    b = pd.DataFrame()
    b['MessageID'] = [28, 21, 4, 3, 18, 99, 22, 102, 1]
    b['NewMessageID'] = [10, 9, 18, 6, 22, 102, 23, 118, 20]
    b = b.rename(columns={'MessageID': 'Start', 'NewMessageID': 'End'})
    rows_to_drop = []
    for i, row in b.iterrows():
        recursion(i, row, b, rows_to_drop)
    b.drop(index=rows_to_drop, inplace=True)


def recursion(i, row, b, rows_to_drop):
    exists = b[b['Start'] == row['End']]
    if not exists.empty and i not in rows_to_drop and exists.index[0] not in rows_to_drop:
        b.at[i, 'End'] = exists['End']
        rows_to_drop.append(exists.index[0])
        for _i, _row in b.iterrows():
            recursion(_i, _row, b, rows_to_drop)
```

Output:

```
   Start  End
0     28   10
1     21    9
2      4   23
3      3    6
5     99  118
8      1   20
```

It clearly is suboptimal - we are iterating over a dataframe here. But it should do the trick, and be efficient enough for relatively small datasets.

It has yet another upside - we are maintaining the input order.

Answer (score 1):

I have probably the nicest solution (maybe the best performing one as you do not have to merge or join anything), though it took me a while. Try:

```py
Me_in_New = np.where(np.in1d(df['MessageID'], df['NewMessageID']) == True)[0]
New = df['NewMessageID'][Me_in_New]
old_location = np.where(np.in1d(df['NewMessageID'], df['MessageID']) == True)[0]
df['NewMessageID'][old_location] = New.values
df = df.drop(Me_in_New)
df.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Let me know if it works!